# Error Message: Unable to resolve interface type > 'Android.Gms.Common.Apis.GoogleApiClient/IConnectionCallbacks'

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am a new Xamarin programmer. I was building an application via the simulator in Visual Studio 2017 for Mac and one day I saw the android version would not build. Since I was doing development primarily for iOS I procrastinated and pushed it for later. I now have an Android device to test on but I am getting this message:

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3):
>   Error XA4204: Unable to resolve interface type
>   'Android.Gms.Common.Apis.GoogleApiClient/IConnectionCallbacks'. Are
>   you missing an assembly reference? (XA4204) (prayupapp.Droid)

I saw that the Google Play Store location services nuget used that so I even installed that Nuget and it still can't find that one reference. As a non android person I have no clue how to begin debugging this. Its crashing in Java here:

> ResolvedAssemblies="@(_ResolvedAssemblies)"

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to solve it?

Comment: Any news on this one? I am facing the same issue after using Xamarin.Forms.Maps. I have already added the reference to Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps but the issue is still there.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue. You should be getting this issue because you have multiple versions of the GooglePlayServices in your Android project.

In my case, I had a Nuget package called SimpleLocation which was using an old version of GooglePlayServices (29.0.0.2). I updated this package (SimpleLocation) to its latest version which was using GooglePlayServices 60.1142.1 and the solution is building successfully now.

Have a look at the error message provided by Visual Studio and find the name of the Nuget package which is using an old version of the GooglePlayServices... in my case was SimpleLocation... Remove this Nuget package and comment out the code using this package and try to build your solution again.

I hope it helps.